# Python: IPC method

Tags: python, ipc

I have 2 separate process, one program need to deliver message to the other one. Currently I am writing the message to the other program via a common folder. I would think this is not an efficient method. Therefore I would like to see for alternative.

Would anyone suggest a better method (except socket)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's wrong with sockets ? It the same as your method, except the shared file is specifically chosen to be read/write fast and there is a huge amount of libraries and documentation in order to avoid process communication pitfalls (mutual exclusion, ...)